# How to change id in the URL for the Page title without a URL field in the db?

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Here is another question for this Great community.
I've been reading about changing this `www.example.com/index.php?id=19`
for `www.example.com/example-page` . I  found a solution :
Creating a URL field in the DB for the page, replacing the identifier ID for the title or whatever. My question is: Is there another way to do that, but without replacing the ID int identifier for the Title?
I mean do this `www.example.com/index.php?id=19`
for `www.example.com/example-page` but still using the id as the unique identifier for the page?.
Because my teacher told me that is more efficient consult numbers than Strings.

Comment: you can use something like www.example.com/example-page-19 or www.example.com/example/page/19 , this way your url is SE friendly and you only need to work with the integer ID

Answer (score 0):

You can use strings as unique identifier - no problem.

I would still advise you to stick to numbers and introduce the string as so called "alias", because you might want to change the string later, and it is very complicated, to update all references to the identifier...